# Output the term title on page--custom.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, taxonomy-terms

I'm pulling my hair out trying to create a custom page--custom.html.twig for a content type and getting taxonomy terms to display.

I'm currently using the following piece of code:

```
{% if node.field_work__services.0 %}
   <ul>
      {% for key, item in node.field_work__services %}
         <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

The if statement resolves, so I get a UL with an equivalent number of LIs to the number of taxonomy terms for that node... however, I can't get it to output the actual taxonomy term.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: As an FYI, I have tried item.value and many others to no avail. Even if i break it out of the conditional and just use node.field_work__services.0.value (or any other key I've tried).. no dice.

Comment: is `page--custom.html.twig` custom template for page, or node ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
{% if node.field_work__services|length %}
      <ul>
        {% for item in node.field_work__services %}
          <li>{{ item.entity.label }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And there you have it! That works wonderfully. Thank you so much! As a bonus, would you happen to know how to get the URL for that as well? I tried item.entity.url_callback and item.entity.links.canonical to no avail....

Comment: Answered my own question here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-04-19/getting-url-of-taxonomy-term-page-from-twig-template